# How to re-do the treehouse support which is failing

Tags: wood-repair

So I built the treehouse with plans from a book and after about eight years one of the support beams is bent and some of the joins have come apart. The plans called for using nails but like adumbass I used screws. It was fine until last year when I noticed this after a storm.

I can do two things. 1) get another 2x6 and put it on top of the existing support and bolt the angled support to it. Basically jack up the sagging side and double up existing support structure or 2) create another triangle support inside the existing one attached to the tree instead of the existing support.

Here are a bunch of pictures to illustrate the problem. Any advice? I’m not opposed to taking the top off and just making it a deck.

Thanks much!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQyuV.jpg

Comment: Just to be clear... the problem here is that the triangular braces have slipped? If so, I'd just remove screws, pull them back to where you want them (braces, ratchet straps) and put a couple of 1/2" through bolts, er, through.

Comment: yup thats the problem. thanks. ill try that. i am also wondering if putting another support on top with bolts and glue would make it stronger.

Comment: *"The plans called for using nails but like adumbass I used screws."* Aaaand? Screws are almost always **better** than nails (better hold, and maintain it longer) so you actually upgraded from the plan! But looking at the pics (esp #2) I'm unsure how that happened (screws bent? tore free from the joist?) so you want to investigate. No great worries here, you can reinforce this no problem in a number of ways (if your current lockdown situation permits you can investigate the various mounting plates at a local hardware store or big-box, there are loads of oddball shapes and 1 or 2 may fit well).

Comment: Safety note: if the plan is to withdraw ANY of these screws (and I mean even just one) you want to add support (e.g. a wedged-in beam) to the underside of a joist *before you start*. You don't want even the possibility of this settling under its weight with the release of even a small portion of the current hold.

Comment: thanks for the advice. i won't take out any screws or bolts because of the danger. its a good point about the mounting. ill check out hd and see if they have metal braces with 45 degree angel. they got to. also, the reason why screws were bad idea is they dont have that much sheer strength, which is exactly what was needed in this case. i.e. better the nails bend a bit, than the whole support sheers off because of lateral stresses in a screw. This is what i understood later when i looked in to it.

Comment: That link will be dead in an internet minute. Better to provide a sketch, even a rough one, of what you are trying to do.

Comment: It seems the size of the screws you used were way too small for tying the braces to the beam.  You have to use heavier lag bolts or through bolts for that joint.  You did use the heavy bolts when attaching to the tree.